# How to style an element only if it contains a specific element with a specific class

Tags: html, css

I have the following element:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="col">MyColumn</div>
</div>
```

I want to style the `parent` class only if it contains a class with class `col`

Comment: yes I did and did use it as inspiration for my final solution

Comment: @TemaniAfif how it is duplicate? Please just don't check the title but also try to understand the actual requirement. For more details please check the answer posted by OP. Thanks!

Comment: @VicJordan well, check your answer and you will see how it's a duplicate .. you used the `has` selector (one of the answer in the duplicate)... then if *you* read again the question you will see it's about styling `parent` if it contains `col` which means style the *parent element* of `col` that contains `parent` which means we need to have a **parent selector** ... don't tell me that all the answers of the duplicate don't apply here? if you are not convinced I can use all the answers there to this particular case. And again, your answer is already similar to the answer already provided

Answer (score 0):

Below are two options to do it using `jQuery`:

**Option 1**

```js
$('.parent').has('.col').addClass('style');
```

```css
.style {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="col">MyColumn</div>
</div>
```

**Option 2**

```js
if ($(".col").parents(".parent").length == 1) {
  // add style here
  $(".parent").css({'background': "red"});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="col">MyColumn</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this is good. but i have another solution. You use jQuery to add a class for parent and style for this class. It will better

Comment: Downvoter... could you please specify the reason to downvote? I will improve that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Threw together a fairly legacy compatible JavaScript version:

```js
var parents = document.querySelectorAll('.parent')

for (var i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < parents[i].children.length; j++) {
    if (hasClass(parents[i].children[j], 'col')) {
      updateCss(parents[i])
    }
  }
}

function hasClass(element, className) {
  return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + className+ ' ') > -1;
}

function updateCss (parent) {
  // whatever you want to add here...
  parent.style.color = 'red';
}
```

```css
.parent {
  margin: 15px;
  outline: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="col">MyColumn</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="something-else">not column</div>
      <div class="col">MyColumn</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="something-else">not column</div>
    </div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In JQuery you can use the `:has` selector, like this:

```
$('.parent:has(.col)').css(/* your css */);
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance wouldn't JQuery use polyfills for the browser support? It's just the browser CSS spec that doesn't include that selector yet I thought.

Comment: @DanielThompson The answer was edited. It originally used only a plain CSS selector.

Comment: @CertainPerformance is right, it won't Work in pure css, that's why I edited it to use JQuery, which Works in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I've come up with so far. what I'm trying to do is to spread the div's with class COL in the remaining space after the size specific col's.

it's still not perfect and needs a little tweaking, but a step in the right direction.

```
var mediaBase = parseFloat(8.33333);

    $.each($("div.row"), function (index) {
        var gens = 0;
        var total = 0;

        $.each($(this).find("div[class^='col']"), function (ii) {
            if (total > 100) {
                $(this).hide();
            }
            else {
                if ($(this).attr("class").indexOf("-") > 0) {
                    let tmp = $(this).attr("class");
                    tmp = parseInt(tmp.slice(tmp.lastIndexOf("-") + 1));

                    total += parseFloat(mediaBase * tmp);
                }
                else {
                    gens++;
                }
            }
        });

        if (gens > 0 && total < 100) {
            let val = (100 - total) / gens;

            if (total === 0) {
                val = 100 / gens;
            }

            $(this).find("div.col").css("width", val.toString() + "%");
        }
    });
```